# 401.2 Error in ASP.Net 2.0 on IIS 7.0 on Windows 2008

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, windows-server-2008, windows-authentication

My "*Hello World*" c#.Net application works fine on my local Windows 7. Moving to our server I get 401.2 error.

Here what I have done (following advices in some forums):

1. Changed the Anonymous authentication use to application pull user
2. Created a new application pull
3. Created a new Windows user with access to application folders
4. Set the authentication of the application pull to that user
5. Set the application pull for my application to that application pull

Please note that:

1. I receive the error both from within the server and outside
2. I receive this error from all the browser I tested: Chrome, IE 9.0 and Firefox
3. An html file in the same folder is visible

What am I missing?
Thanks,
Asaf

Comment: It may be caused by windows authentication, have u checked that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to create a new windows user. I know you've said what steps you've done, but I'm going to highlight what I do each time I add a new site.

- Set the Identity of the Application Pool to
  `ApplicationPoolIdentity`.
- In the website, set `Anonymous Authentication` to `Enabled`. Click
  Edit on the right and set the `Authentication Credentials` to
  `Application pool identity`.
- In the website, again, choose `Basic Settings` on the right. Click
  the `Connect As..` button and make sure `Application User` is
  selected.
- Give the appropriate access to the folder on your hard drive(s); i.e
  Application Pool name = hello.com, the user is `IIS
  AppPool\hello.com`.

I think your issue is that you haven't given the folder permissions for the Application Pool User. I think you've incorrectly given them to an unneccessary Windows account.
HTH

Comment: Hello @ianbaily and thank you for your reply. In the first step - The identity of the Application Pool can be LocalService/LocalSystem/NetworkService. Could not find ApplicationPullIdentity, is it the Idntity of the application?

Comment: Under the `Advanced Settings` in the ApplicationPools area, look under Process Model --> Identity. Under Built-in Accounts, ApplicationPoolIdentity is the last one. I tend to avoid using NetworkService as using the ApplicationPoolIdentity keeps everything more segregated.

Comment: You're welcome :-) It had me puzzled for ages when I first came across the issue as well, so glad to pass on the knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the correct version of .NET installed on Server? Also you need to register ASP.NET in IIS - c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\framework\v2.0.50727 (or v4.0....) 
aspnet_regiis.exe -i

and after restart IIS with iisreset in command line

Comment: Thanks @Ivan, for getting back to me. Having ran these 2 commands I still get "Access is denied". Why do you feel your re-installing .Net Framework is related to this autohrization issue?